# WSO2 ESB 5.0 Source Code

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I now use WSO2 ESB 5.0 version, I would like to ask where to download the corresponding version of the source code and compile operation?

Understand the WSO2 ESB is based on the carbon, Carbon directory contains orbit, kernel, platform, need to compile orbit, then kernel, then platform. I have svn: `https: //svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon` view the source of carbon, and from svn see the three directories under the maximum number of 4.2.0, which platform maximum version is 4.1.7, because we do not know wso2 esb 5.0 version of the corresponding orbit, kernel, platform which is the specific version, it is not clear which version of the download?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

See release matrix : http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

WSO2 ESB v5 source code is now in GitHub, see

- https://wso2.github.io/
- https://github.com/wso2
- https://github.com/wso2/product-esb